# Show image when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript I would like to show a working/loading image once a user hits submit on my form.  The form is used to upload video's so it can take a while for the file to upload.  Once the file is done uploading the page reloads so the loading image would not need to be visible anymore.

Can anyone help me with this please?

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120000" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="yes"> 

First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> 

Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br> 

Email Confirmation: <input type="text" name="email2"><br> 

Video Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br> 

Video Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br> 

Video to upload: <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br> 

Terms: <input type="checkbox" name="terms"> Must be checked to accept our terms of service.<br><br> 

<input type="submit" value="Upload Video"> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery: you can use as follow within document.ready

```
$("form").submit(function() { //you can assign id to your form and used that id instead of form
$("#iamgeid").show();
return true;
});
```

Comment: I changes it to  `$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form").submit(function() { //you can assign id to your form and used that id instead of form
 $("#imageid").show();
 return true;
 });
});` and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Normally We cannot display a loading image after submitting a form, because when we submit a form initially it sends request to the server and the loading is only because of the server response after uploading. loading image will not animate while server is loading.
To show the loading image we have to do some tricks.
**1.** We should not submit the form in the same window, instead we have to post the form to a iframe. this can be done by adding the target attribute to the form tag.
<div id="form-container">
     <form ... action="uploadfilepath" target="iframe_name">
        ...................... 
        ...................... 
     </form>
</div>
<iframe name="iframe-name" onsubmit="showimage()" style="width:1px; height:1px; visibility:hidden;"></iframe>

**2.** We have to add the script to show image when server is loading inside the iframe.
<img src="loading image path" id="image-container">

<script>
     function showimage() {
          document.getElementById('form-container').style.display='none';
          document.getElementById('image-container').style.display='block';
     }
</script>

**3.** Also add the script after uploading the file.
.......................................
.......................................
 your file uploading 
 code goes here  
.......................................
.......................................
at the end print the script to reload the parent window or call the function in parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be an AJAX call to do the whole thing.

Place an image with display: none on the desired location and then do this small thing:

```
var d = document;
var demoInterval;
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("img").show();
    demoInterval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 1000);
});
function intervalFunc()
{
    if(d.ready) // finished uploading video
    {
        window.clearInterval(demoInterval);
        $("img").hide();
    }
}
```